# Add delete button to UICollection View

Tags: ios, directory, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I want to add a delete button to a UICollection View so when the user taps on delete button he taps on the photo he does not like and is deleted automatically and can tap the delete button again to finish his task, However, I have a problem.  I am showing pictures straight from a folder in the directory which is hard to delete.  How can I accomplish the task?  I was able to delete pictures from the UICollection View, However, could not from the directory.  What should I do to do this?

Update

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    int row = [indexPath row];
    [self.allimagesArray removeObjectAtIndex:row];
    NSArray *deleteItems = @[indexPath];
    [self.collectionHats deleteItemsAtIndexPaths:deleteItems];
}
```

I used a simple code for first and have failed to delete , I did not put a button aswell this is all from this code.

Comment: please post the code where you have tried to delete the file.

Answer (score 0):

You can delete files with [`NSFileManager`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html) [`removeItemAtURL:error:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000305-SW15).

Like so:

```
NSError *error = nil;
if (![NSFileManager sharedManager] removeItemAtURL:yourFileURL error:&error]) {
    NSLog(@"Failed to delete file: %@", error);
}
```

Comment: Also I can't do the action where user taps button and goes to delete mode and taps picture and delete and when user is finished with deleted he pushes the button again and is back to viewmode.For simplicity I want to make it like the photo's app in ios but won't go like that.  I have set an bar Button item called delete and I am stuck there.

Comment: You are just ask way to much for us to solve. Try it step by step. You will have to solve this your self since we are not here to code for you.